# Solving a recurrence relation. Check my answer

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence relation:

```
T(n)=4 for n<=2
T(n)=3T(n/3)+5 for n>2
```

So I began solving it,

```
T(n/3)=3T(n/9)+5
then 
T(n)=3(3T(n/9)+5)+5
= 3^k T(n/3^k)+5k
letting k=log_3_n
= 3^log_3_n T(n/3^log_3_n)+5log_3_n
= nT(1)+5log_3_n
= 4n+5log_3_n
```

Is this the correct answer?
I am confused on the part where there is +5k. Is that part correct?

Comment: $T(n)=3(3T(n/9)+5)+5=3^2T(n/9)+5\cdot(3+1)$ and so one. That was the mistake.

Comment: @TheGreatSeo How would u express that in terms of k though?

Comment: @SamIAm There's no $k$ in the problem...

Comment: @SamIAm You have to use something like $\sum3^i$. Then you can simplify that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **generalized Josephus recurrence**, of which an in-depth solution is given in *Concrete Mathematics* (by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik).

> If $f$ is defined as:
>
> $$\begin{align}f(j) &= \alpha_j & \text{for }1\le j\lt d\\
> f(dn+j) &= cf(n)+\beta_j & \text{for } 0 \le j \lt d\text{ and } n\ge 1
> \end{align}$$
>
> Then $f\left((b_mb_{m-1}\dots b_1b_0)_d\right) = (\alpha_{b_m}\beta_{b_{m-1}}\beta_{b_{m-2}}\dots\beta_{b_1}\beta_{b_0})_c$
>   (where $(b_mb_{m-1}\dots b_1b_0)_d$ is the radix-$d$ representation of $n$).

Applied to your problem, we have $d = 3$, $\alpha_j = 4$, $c = 3$, and $\beta_j = 5$.

Thus, your solution is:
$$\begin{align}
f\left((b_mb_{m-1}\dots b_1b_0)_d\right) &= (\alpha_{b_m}\beta_{b_{m-1}}\beta_{b_{m-2}}\dots\beta_{b_1}\beta_{b_0})_c\\
&= \underbrace{(4\;5\;5\dots5\;5)_3}_{m+1\text{ digits}}\\
&= \underbrace{(5\;5\;5\dots5\;5)_3}_{m+1\text{ digits}} - 3^{m} \\
&= 5\cdot \underbrace{(1\;1\dots1\;1)_3}_{m+1\text{ digits}} - 3^{m} \\
&= 5\left(\frac{3^{m+1}-1}{2}\right) - 3^{m}
\end{align}$$

(Where $m+1$ is the number of digits in the base-$3$ representation of $n$.)

Comment: I appear to have an off-by-one error.  It's too late at night for me to correct it, so I'll come back to this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is correct. I don't see any problems with your answer.

Comment: Thanks but i am confused on the part where I get 5k. Shouldnt it be 5^k?

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry. Definitely a 5^k there :P. Accidentally skipped over that.

I'll double check again to make sure your working is fully correct.

Comment: Other than that its fine.

Comment: I found other example showing that it should be something like (3^k-1)*5. Which one would be correct?